# Is it normal to be signed out of all services and accounts when moving iOS devices?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

today I replaced my iPad because the old one was damaged. I restored from an iCloud backup. The restore went ok, but I must re-authenticate / sign-in to every app which connects to a web backend (which these days is all of them.) e.g. my banking apps didn’t know who I was.

Basically this will soak up most of my afternoon.

I have a vague memory that I did not used to have to do this in the old days of iOS, Maybe because I used to use iTunes backups...?

Anyway, I just wanted to check. Is this normal?